# Kentico error The file '/CMSModules/Chat/Controls/SupportChatHeader.ascx' does not exist

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc

I'm trying to setup a development machine for upgrading Kentico 11 to 12. Version 11 is under TFS source control and packages are not added to source control.

On dev machine I used NuGet to add Kentico.Libraries and Kentico.Libraries.Web.UI  packages.

The solution on dev machine is compiling, but I'm getting this runtime error when I try to browse to Kentico CMS

```
The file '/CMSModules/Chat/Controls/SupportChatHeader.ascx' does not exist
```

[image: YSOD screenshot]

Comment: I assume the file is present on disk and included into the web application project, right? If yes, could you please describe the upgrade steps in more details?

Comment: @jurajo upgrade process hasn't been started yet. so far. i was just trying to make sure the solution complies on my local machine. and no, the file or folder mentioned in the error do not exist on local disk or in the published working version on Azure..here is a screenshot from Azure kudu tools: https://imgur.com/a/01DoX7I

Comment: I just commented the `EnsureSupportChat();` line in `CMS\CMSAdminControls\UI\Header.ascx.cs` and now I can see the Admin dashboard. Hopefully someone can point to a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that the missing files been removed or were not added to TFS, which would go some way to explain their absence.  If you have other functioning environments (UAT or perhaps production), then I would think about copying the files back from them to update the local environment.

I have had a similar issue once before, but we found that the upgrade replaced the missing files for us, so it may be worth just giving the upgrade a shot.

Comment: The functioning environment does not have that folder/file so I have no way of copying the "missing" file back. Maybe the path is virtual that's why it's not present on file system?

Comment: This is a physical path rather than virtual. If you have the Kentico installation manager, you can create a blank v11 site and then copy the missing files into your project. Understanding why they are no longer there is a good thing to find out too to make sure that it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a couple of times when upgrading with Kentico hotfixes. In my particular case I did not require the `CMS.Chat` module so uninstalled it via the Kentico Installation Manager. However, because my CMS project had a reference to the `Kentico.Libraries` NuGet package, my `CMSApp` project had assembly references added back to the `CMS.Chat.dll` assembly - this time referenced from the NuGet package folder.

In this case I simply removed the assembly references to the DLLs I did not need so that they were not copied to the `bin` folder. I think if the DLL is present in the `bin` folder then Kentico considers the module to be present and will then try to load the controls, but of course if the Kentico module was uninstalled then so were the ASCX files, which is what causes the exception.